# Displaying output under a certain format

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, output

I'm quite new to Scala and Spark, and had some questions about displaying results in output file.

I actually have a Map in which each key is associated to a List of List (`Map[Int, List<Double>]`), such as :

```
 (2, List(x1,x2,x3), List(y1,y2,y3), ...).
```

I am supposed to display for each key the values inside the lists of lists, such as:

```
2     x1,x2,x3
2     y1,y2,y3
1     z1,z2,z3
```

and so on.

When I use the `saveAsTextFile` function, it doesn't give me what I want in the output. Does anybody know how I can do it?

EDIT :
This is one of my function :

```
 def PrintCluster(vectorsByKey : Map[Int, List[Double]], vectCentroidPairs : Map[Int, Int]) : Map[Int, List[Double]] = {

    var vectorsByCentroid: Map[Int, List[Double]] = Map()
    val SortedCentroid = vectCentroidPairs.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(x => x.map(_._1).toList).toSeq.sortBy(_._1).toMap 
    SortedCentroid.foreach { case (centroid, vect) => 
      var nbVectors = vect.length

      for (i <- 0 to nbVectors - 1) {
        var vectValues = vectorsByKey(vect(i))
        println(centroid + "  " + vectValues)
        vectorsByCentroid += (centroid -> (vectValues))
      }
    }
    return vectorsByCentroid
  }
```

I know it's wrong, because I only can affect one unique keys for a group of values. That is why it returns me only the first List for each key in the Map. I thought that for using the *saveAsTextFile* function, I've had necessarily to use a Map structure, but I don't really know.

Comment: What does `saveAsTextFile` give you and how does it differ from what you want? Also it doesn't look like you have list of lists but normal lists (`Map[Int, List[Double]]`)?

Comment: You might want to show your Scala code. Also, try writing a Dataset using the CSV format but set the delimiter to a tab

Comment: @Shaido The output I have is logic, I mean... Since I can have only one single key for a value (map format), only the first value is printed. This is what I get : (3,List(-2.7, 6.1, -2.8)),  (2,List(-2.7, 7.1, -2.8)).

Comment: I don't really know how it works to be quite honest. I'm not supposed to display the parenthesis for example. That's why I'm wondering if I can do something manually with a String, or if it must be necessarily a map for the saveAsTextFile function...

Comment: @Sol If I understand correctly, you want the method to return `Map[Int, List[List[Double]]]` (list of list instead of only list)? It does not seem to have anything to do with Spark though, only scala.

Comment: @Shaido ! It's good. I have such a Map. Now, my question is, how I can display my values as mentionned... ?

Comment: @Sol Added an answer that should take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Map[Int, List[List[Double]]]` and simply print it in the format wanted is simple, it can be done by first converting to a list and then applying `flatMap`. Using the data supplied in a comment:

```
val map: Map[Int, List[List[Double]]] = Map(
  2 -> List(List(-4.4, -2.0, 1.5), List(-3.3, -5.4, 3.9), List(-5.8, -3.3, 2.3), List(-5.2, -4.0, 2.8)), 
  1 -> List(List(7.3, 1.0, -2.0), List(9.8, 0.4, -1.0), List(7.5, 0.3, -3.0), List(6.1, -0.5, -0.6), List(7.8, 2.2, -0.7), List(6.6, 1.4, -1.1), List(8.1, -0.0, 2.7)), 
  3 -> List(List(-3.0, 4.0, 1.4), List(-4.0, 3.9, 0.8), List(-1.4, 4.3, -0.5), List(-1.6, 5.2, 1.0))
) 

val list = map.toList.flatMap(t => t._2.map((t._1, _)))
val result = for (t <- list) yield t._1 + "\t" + t._2.mkString(",")

// Saving the result to file
import java.io._
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("fileName.txt"))
result.foreach{ line => pw.println(line)}
pw.close
```

Will print out:

```
2   -4.4,-2.0,1.5
2   -3.3,-5.4,3.9
2   -5.8,-3.3,2.3
2   -5.2,-4.0,2.8
1   7.3,1.0,-2.0
1   9.8,0.4,-1.0
1   7.5,0.3,-3.0
1   6.1,-0.5,-0.6
1   7.8,2.2,-0.7
1   6.6,1.4,-1.1
1   8.1,-0.0,2.7
3   -3.0,4.0,1.4
3   -4.0,3.9,0.8
3   -1.4,4.3,-0.5
3   -1.6,5.2,1.0
```

Comment: It works! But doesn't display anything as output... Is it normal?

Comment: @Sol It should print the lines with `println()`. Included code so you get a `List[String]` as a result as well.

Comment: I mean... How can I put this algorithm in the saveAsTextFile?

Comment: Do you have the data in a RDD or Map? If it's a Map then using another function to save it would be easier.

Comment: I suppose it is a map, since I just have Map[Int, List[List[Double]]]... ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, a lot, a lot. But I don't have the right to use extra librairies haha...

Comment: But you can use `saveAsTextFile`? Try `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(result).saveAsTextFile("fileName")`. In that case, it would probably be easier for you to work with a RDD instead of a Map. `spark` here is `val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

create sample rdd as per your input data

```
val rdd: RDD[Map[Int, List[List[Double]]]] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(Map(
    2 -> List(List(-4.4, -2.0, 1.5), List(-3.3, -5.4, 3.9), List(-5.8, -3.3, 2.3), List(-5.2, -4.0, 2.8)),
    1 -> List(List(7.3, 1.0, -2.0), List(9.8, 0.4, -1.0), List(7.5, 0.3, -3.0), List(6.1, -0.5, -0.6), List(7.8, 2.2, -0.7), List(6.6, 1.4, -1.1), List(8.1, -0.0, 2.7)),
    3 -> List(List(-3.0, 4.0, 1.4), List(-4.0, 3.9, 0.8), List(-1.4, 4.3, -0.5), List(-1.6, 5.2, 1.0)))
  )
)
```

Transform `RDD[Map[Int, List[List[Double]]]]` to `RDD[(Int, String)]`

```
val result: RDD[(Int, String)] = rdd.flatMap(i => {
  i.map {
    case (x, y) => y.map(list => (x, list.mkString(" ")))
  }
}).flatMap(z => z)

result.foreach(println)

result.saveAsTextFile("location")
```

Comment: Not really. In fact I have a function (void) that prints for each Key the value (x, y, z). So I know it works. The problem is I don't know how to return a correct format to display the result I want. If I return a result, it can't be a map since a map has a unique key and I have several values sharing the same key. That is why my output doesn't give me the good thing. 

These are my last lines :
`val mapResult = PrintCluster(vectKeys, vectCentroidPair)

sc.parallelize(mapResult.toSeq, 2).saveAsTextFile("result")`

Comment: Can you check the edit. If not, try add the sample input rdd.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused about my proper code. I edited my post. In fact, 

I have two Maps really important :
The first one : vectorsByKey, match one random key for each vector, such as : `Map(25, list(x,y,z))`. The second one : vectCentroidPairs, match each vector under its random key value with the matching centroid (K-mean algorithm). I have something like that : `Map(1, List(5, 37, 25, 78, 70, 33, 53, 41, 32, 64, 27)).`
What I have to do is to retrieve the real values under the key (so the lists) and display it for each matching centroid (1, 2 or 3).

Comment: This is finally what I have, a Map[Int, List[List[Double]]] : 
Map(2 -> List(List(-4.4, -2.0, 1.5), List(-3.3, -5.4, 3.9), List(-5.8, -3.3, 2.3),  List(-5.2, -4.0, 2.8)),
 1 -> List(List(7.3, 1.0, -2.0), List(9.8, 0.4, -1.0),  List(7.5, 0.3, -3.0), List(6.1, -0.5, -0.6), List(7.8, 2.2, -0.7), List(6.6, 1.4, -1.1), List(8.1, -0.0, 2.7)),
 3 -> List(List(-3.0, 4.0, 1.4), List(-4.0, 3.9, 0.8), List(-1.4, 4.3, -0.5), List(-1.6, 5.2, 1.0)))